# Angular How to update a element width according to the another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

On my page, the left side I have a side bar menu with can be hide and show. and on the right side is the main page content, it changes its width according to the status of the sidebar.

Now In the main page content I have a div which has been set as position:fixed on the top of the screen. I want this div keep the same width as the main page and get updated each time the main page content width has changed( when side bar hide/show or the window width has been changed) how to make this in angular please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show us the code that you are working with otherwise it would be very hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery, You can change the width of one element same as other element using following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".second_elem").css({
    'width': ($(".first_elem").width() + 'px')
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, but, this can only set fixed element's width one single time when document is ready. when I resize the window or when the sidebar is appeared, it's width is not updated.

Comment: Does width of original element changes? Can we put a watch on it?